# ID lookup from an external file in JQ

Tags: json, jq

I have a lookup file that maps IDs from one system onto another:

```
[
  {
    "idA": 2547,
    "idB": "5d0bf91d191c6554d14572a6"
  },
  {
    "idA": 2549,
    "idB": "5b0473f93d4e53db19f8c249"
  },
  {
    "idA": 2550,
    "idB": "5d0bfabc8f20917b92ff07dc"
  },
...
```

And I have a data file with values and an ID from one of these systems:

```
[
  {
    "idB": "5d0bf91d191c6554d14572a6",
    "description": "Description for 5d0bf91d191c6554d14572a6"
  },
  {
    "idB": "5d0bf49e9236c57281811cfc",
    "description": "Description for 5d0bf49e9236c57281811cfc"
  },
  {
    "idB": "5d0bfabc8f20917b92ff07dc",
    "description": "Description for 5d0bfabc8f20917b92ff07dc"
  },
...
```

I want to produce a new file of the descriptions with their IDs converted to the `idA` values in the lookup file. I tried this:

```
jq --slurpfile idmap ids.json 'map( {"description":.description, "id": (.idB as $b|$idmap[][]|select(.idB==$b)|.idA) } )' descriptions.json
```

But it produces only an empty array.

I have to double-dereference `$idmap` because slurping a file "binds an array of the parsed JSON values to the given global variable" -- so just doing `$idmap[]` throws an error, **jq: error (at descriptions.json:70): Cannot index array with string "idB"**.

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: it doesn't look like any of the idB from the second file in your example match the idB from the first file in your example?  I get an empty array as well.  However, if I mark up the second file to use the same idB as the first, then I get something back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a concise and straightforward solution to the stated problem.

For simplicity, we'll begin by constructing a dictionary containing the relevant mapping using `INDEX/2`:

```
INDEX($idmap[]; .idB) | map_values(.idA)
```

Now the task is easy:

```
(INDEX($idmap[]; .idB) | map_values(.idA)) as $dict
| map( {description, "idA": $dict[.idB] } )
```

This assumes an invocation that uses --argfile idmap ids.json to avoid
the unwanted "slurping" caused by --slurpfile, but if the latter is used, then you would use `$idmap[][]` instead as noted in the original question.

Since the sample snippets do not include any matching "idB" values, there is little point in showing the output that would be obtained using these snippets.

### Variation

If the objects in `descriptions.js` had other keys that should be retained, then the following variant would probably be a more useful guide:

```
(INDEX($idmap[]; .idB) | map_values(.idA)) as $dict    # or $idmap[][] as above
| map( .idA = $dict[.idB] | del(.idB) )
```

Comment: Thanks, and sorry for the bad data. Again because of the way slurpfile works, I had to change `$idmap[]` to `$idmap[][]` but otherwise it was perfect. I haven't paid enough attention to the new "SQL-style" stuff in 1.6.

Comment: @Ken - I had meant to include the comment (now added) about --slurpfile.  Thanks for pointing out the error.